# How to properly re sign a shell script

Tags: powershell, certificate, self-signed

I have never done a self signed certificate in Windows 10 or any other OS, but I did manage to do so by  following the steps in [this link](https://adamtheautomator.com/how-to-sign-powershell-script/#:%7E:text=To%20do%20so%3A%201%20In%20Windows%20Explorer%2C%20navigate,see%20a%20digital%20signature%20under%20the%20Signature%20list.)

But after that success I realize that I need to make changes to the script and re-sign it.

The author of the article does instruct to re-sign the script after a changes are made. But here is where I struggle.

Here are the steps I follows after I change the script to resign after updating the script.

```
> $codeCertificate = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq "CN=ATA Authenticode"}
```

Then

```
> Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\ATA\myscript.ps1 -Certificate $codeCertificate -TimeStampServer http://timestamp.digicert.com
```

But I get an `UnknownError` with the message `No provider was specified for the store or object.`

I did try to search for the error but found nothing, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to run `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` in an admin console. Start > powershell > right click > launch as administrator.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick, I forgot to do that after resetting the terminal